# Qiskit's draw only shows the circuit's name and not the architecture

Tags: qiskit

Upon trying to draw a `ZZFeatureMap` instance, I only see the name "ZZFeatureMap" and not its architecture. Please find the code snippet and output attached:

```python
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZZFeatureMap
zz = ZZFeatureMap(2, entanglement="full", reps=2)
zz.draw("mpl")
```

[image]

However, `print(zz)` prints the architecture of the circuit but it is not drawn with matplotlib.

[image]

Please help me draw the internals of the architecture of circuit with the `draw()` function. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`decompose` method of a `QuantumCircuit` object](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.decompose.html):

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZZFeatureMap
zz = ZZFeatureMap(2, entanglement="full", reps=2)
zz.decompose().draw("mpl")
```

[image: Circuit with decomposition]